# Why is my png files updated into database as pdf and how to correct it?

Tags: php, html

I know, my question must be really basic, but I decided to ask since when I go through this site, I couldn't find the solution from the previous similar problems.

Here it is, I have a system where a user have to upload their resume and their profile picture into the system in order to create their account. The registration is successful, however, their profile picture is not displayed and when I check in my database, the name of their resume and their profile picture is the same although when I checked inside the uploaded files respectively, the resume and picture are inside their respective folders.

Here what my DB looks like:

[image: logo and resume side by side]

and here is my adduser.php

```html
<?php

//To Handle Session Variables on This Page
session_start();

//Including Database Connection From db.php file to avoid rewriting in all files
require_once("db.php");

//If user Actually clicked register button
if(isset($_POST)) {
 $user_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['user_name']);
 $ic_no = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['ic_no']);
 $nationality = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['nationality']);
 $gender = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['gender']);
 $race = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['race']);
 $ic_no = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['ic_no']);
 $contactno = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['contactno']);
 $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['email']);
 $address = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['address']);
 $highest_qualification = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['highest_qualification']);
 $university = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['university']);
 $major = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['major']);
 $current_position = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['current_position']);
 $position_applied = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['position_applied']);
 $current_monthly_salary = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['current_monthly_salary']);
 $expected_monthly_salary = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['expected_monthly_salary']);
 $prefered_working_location = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['prefered_working_location']);
 $avaibility = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['avaibility']);
 $malay = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['malay']);
 $english = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['english']); 
 $mandarin = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['mandarin']);
 $other = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['other']);
 $aboutme = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['aboutme']);

    
 $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['password']);
 $password = base64_encode(strrev(md5($password)));

    //sql query to check if email already exists or not
    $sql = "SELECT email FROM users WHERE email='$email'";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    //if email not found then we can insert new data
    if($result->num_rows == 0) {

            //This variable is used to catch errors doing upload process. False means there is some error and we need to notify that user.
    $uploadOk = true;



 // Code for image
$folder_dir = "uploads/logo/";
$base = basename($_FILES['image']['name']); 
$imageFileType = pathinfo($base, PATHINFO_EXTENSION); 
$file = uniqid() . "." . $imageFileType; 
$filename = $folder_dir .$file;  

  if(file_exists($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'])) { 

            if($imageFileType == "jpg" || $imageFileType == "png")  {

                if($_FILES['image']['size'] < 500000) { // File size is less than 5MB

                    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"], $filename);

                } else {
                 
                    $_SESSION['uploadError'] = "Wrong Size. Max Size Allowed : 5MB";
                    $uploadOk = false;
                }
            } else {
                $_SESSION['uploadError'] = "Wrong Format. Only jpg & png Allowed";
                $uploadOk = false;
            }
        } else {
                $_SESSION['uploadError'] = "Something Went Wrong. File Not Uploaded. Try Again.";
                $uploadOk = false;
            }

  // Code for resume

 
    $folder_dir = "uploads/resume/";
    $base = basename($_FILES['resume']['name']); 
    $resumeFileType = pathinfo($base, PATHINFO_EXTENSION); 
    $file1 = uniqid() . "." . $resumeFileType;   
    $filename = $folder_dir .$file1;  
    if(file_exists($_FILES['resume']['tmp_name'])) { 

        if($resumeFileType == "pdf"|| $resumeFileType == "doc")  {
            if($_FILES['resume']['size'] < 500000) { 
   
                move_uploaded_file($_FILES["resume"]["tmp_name"], $filename);

            } else {
              
                $_SESSION['uploadError'] = "Wrong Size. Max Size Allowed : 5MB";
                $uploadOk = false;
            }
        } else {
        
            $_SESSION['uploadError'] = "Wrong Format. Only PDF Allowed";
            $uploadOk = false;
        }
    } else {
            //File not copied to temp location error.
            $_SESSION['uploadError'] = "Something Went Wrong. File Not Uploaded. Try Again.";
            $uploadOk = false;
        }

    //If there is any error then redirect back.
    if($uploadOk == false) {
        header("Location: register-candidates.php");
        exit();
    }

        $hash = md5(uniqid());


        //sql new registration insert query
  $sql="INSERT INTO users (user_name, ic_no, gender, email, password, address, nationality, contactno, highest_qualification, university, major, current_position,
  position_applied, current_monthly_salary, expected_monthly_salary, prefered_working_location, avaibility, malay, english, mandarin, other, logo, resume, hash, aboutme) VALUES
  ('$user_name', '$ic_no', '$gender', '$email', '$password', '$address', '$nationality', '$contactno', '$highest_qualification', '$university', '$major', '$current_position',
  '$position_applied', '$current_monthly_salary', '$expected_monthly_salary', '$prefered_working_location', '$avaibility', '$malay', '$english', '$mandarin',
  '$other', '$file', '$file1', '$hash', '$aboutme')";
  
  
  
        if($conn->query($sql)===TRUE) {
            // Send Email

            // $to = $email;

            // $subject = "Job Portal - Confirm Your Email Address";

            // $message = '

            // <html>
            // <head>
            //  <title>Confirm Your Email</title>
            // <body>
            //  <p>Click Link To Confirm</p>
            //  <a href="yourdomain.com/verify.php?token='.$hash.'&email='.$email.'">Verify Email</a>
            // </body>
            // </html>
            // ';

            // $headers[] = 'MIME-VERSION: 1.0';
            // $headers[] = 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1';
            // $headers[] = 'To: '.$to;
            // $headers[] = 'From: hello@yourdomain.com';
            // //you add more headers like Cc, Bcc;

            // $result = mail($to, $subject, $message, implode("\r\n", $headers)); // \r\n will return new line. 

            // if($result === TRUE) {

            //  //If data inserted successfully then Set some session variables for easy reference and redirect to login
            //  $_SESSION['registerCompleted'] = true;
            //  header("Location: login.php");
            //  exit();

            // }

            // //If data inserted successfully then Set some session variables for easy reference and redirect to login
            $_SESSION['registerCompleted'] = true;
            header("Location: login-candidates.php");
            exit();
        } else {
            //If data failed to insert then show that error. Note: This condition should not come unless we as a developer make mistake or someone tries to hack their way in and mess up :D
            echo "Error " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
        }
    } else {
        //if email found in database then show email already exists error.
        $_SESSION['registerError'] = true;
        header("Location: candidate-register.php");
        exit();
    }

   
    $conn->close();

} else {
    //redirect them back to register page if they didn't click register button
    header("Location: candidate-register.php");
    exit();
}
?>
```

and also to let you guys see where this php goes, it's in register-candidates.php

```html
<form  method="post" id="registerCandidates" action="adduser.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">


<table border="0" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0">
<p>
<tr> <td colspan="2">
<label for="user_name" type="text" id="user_name" placeholder="user_name" style="color:black;"><b>Full Name *</b></label><br />
<input name="user_name" class="form-control" type="text" maxlength="50" style="width: 560px" required />
</td> </tr>
</p>

<p>
<tr> <td>
<label for="ic_no" type="text" id="ic_no" placeholder="ic_no" style="color:black;"><b>NRIC *</b></label><br />
<input name="ic_no" class="form-control" type="text" maxlength="50" style="width: 235px" required />
</td> 

<td>
<label for="nationality" type="text" id="nationality" placeholder="Nationality" style="color:black;"><b>Nationality</b></label><br />
<input name="nationality" class="form-control" type="text" id="nationality" maxlength="50" style="width: 235px" />
     
 </td>
</tr>
</p>

<p>
<tr> <td>
<label for="gender" type="text" id="gender" placeholder="Gender" style="color:black;"><b>Gender</b></label><br />
<select name = "gender" class ="form-control" type ="text" id="gender"  maxlength="50" style="width: 235px"> <br>
    <option value="">-- select one --</option>
     <option value="Male">Male</option>
     <option value="Female">Female</option>
    </select> 

</td> 

<td>
<label for="race" style="color:black;"><b>Race</b></label><br/>
<select name = "race" class ="form-control" type ="text" id="race"  maxlength="50" style="width: 235px"> <br>
    <option value="">-- select one --</option>
     <option value="Malay">Malay</option>
     <option value="Chinese">Chinese</option>
     <option value="Indian">Indian</option>
     <option value="Others">Others</option>     
    </select>


</td> </tr>  
</p>

<p>
<tr> <td>
<label for="contactno" type="text" id="contactno" placeholder="contactno" style="color:black;"><b>Contact Number *</b></label><br />
<input name="contactno" class="form-control" type="text" maxlength="11" style="width: 235px" />
</td> 

<td>
<label for="email" type="text" id="email" placeholder="Email" style="color:black;"><b>Email</b></label><br />
<input name="email" class="form-control" type="text" maxlength="50" style="width: 235px" />
</td> </tr> 
</p>
  <?php 
     //If User already registered with this email then show error message.
              if(isset($_SESSION['registerError'])) {
                ?>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label style="color: red;">Email Already Exists! Choose A Different Email!</label>
                </div>
              <?php
               unset($_SESSION['registerError']); }
              ?> 

              <?php if(isset($_SESSION['uploadError'])) { ?>
              <div class="form-group">
                  <label style="color: red;"><?php echo $_SESSION['uploadError']; ?></label>
              </div>
              <?php unset($_SESSION['uploadError']); } ?>   

<p>
<tr> <td colspan="2">
<label for="address" type="text" id="address" placeholder="Address" style="color:black;"><b>Current Address</b></label><br />
<textarea class="form-control" rows="4" id="address" name="address" maxlength="100" style="width: 560px"></textarea>
</td> </tr>
</p>

<p>
<tr>
<td colspan="2">
<label for="highest_qualification" type="highest_qualifiation" id="highest_qualification" placeholder="Highest Qualification" style="color:black;"><b>Highest Qualification</b></label><br/>
<select name = "highest_qualification" class="form-control " type="text" id="highest_qualification"  maxlength="50" style="width: 235px"> <br>
    <option value="">-- select one --</option>
     <option value="PhD">PhD</option>
     <option value="Master">Master/Postgraduate</option>
     <option value="Bachelor">Bachelor/Undergraduate</option>
     <option value="Diploma">Diploma</option>     
    </select>
    
   </td></tr>
</p>   

<p>
<tr><td colspan="2">
<label for="university" type="text" id="university" placeholder="University" style="color:black;"><b>University</b></label><br/>
<input name="university" class="form-control" type="text" id="university" maxlength="50" style="width: 235px" /


<tr> <td colspan="2">
<label for="major" type="text" id="major" placeholder="Major" style="color:black;"><b>Major *</b></label><br />
<input name="major" type="text" class="form-control" maxlength="100" style="width: 560px" />
</td> </tr> 

<tr> <td colspan="2">
<label for="current_position" type="text" id="current_position" placeholder="Current Position" style="color:black;"><b>Current Position *</b></label><br />
<input name="current_position" type="text" class="form-control" maxlength="100" style="width: 560px" />
</td> </tr> 

<tr> <td colspan="2">
<label for="position_applied" type="text" id="position_applied" placeholder="Position Applied" style="color:black;"><b>Position Applied*</b></label><br />
<input name="position_applied" type="text" class="form-control" maxlength="100" style="width: 560px" />
</td> </tr> 

<tr> <td>
<label for="current_monthly_salary" type="text" id="current_monthly_salary" placeholder="Current Monthly Salary" style="color:black;"><b>Current Monthly Salary</b></label><br /> 
<input name="current_monthly_salary" type="text" class="form-control" maxlength="50" style="width: 235px" /> 
</td> 


<td>
<label for="expected_monthly_salary" type="text" id="expected_monthly_salary" placeholder="Expected Monthly Salary" style="color:black;"><b>Expected Monthly Salary</b></label><br />
<input name="expected_monthly_salary" type="text" class="form-control" maxlength="50" style="width: 235px" />
</td> </tr> 

<tr> <td colspan="2">
<label for="preferred_working_location" type="text" id="preferred_working_location" placeholder="Preferred working Location" style="color:black;"><b>Preferred working location?</b></label><br />
<input name="preferred_working_location" type="text" class="form-control" maxlength="100" style="width: 560px" />
</td> </tr> 


<tr> <td colspan="2">

<label for="availability" type="availability" id="availability" placeholder="availability" style="color:black;"><b>Availability</b></label><br/>
<select name = "availability" class="form-control " type="text" id="availability"  maxlength="50" style="width: 235px"> <br>
    <option value="">-- select one --</option>
     <option value="Immediately">Immediately</option>
     <option value="One Month">One Month</option>
     <option value="Two Month">Two Month</option>
     <option value="Three Month">Three Month</option>     
    </select>
</td> </tr> 

<tr><td colspan="2">
<label for="language" type="text" id="language" placeholder="Language Proficiency" style="color:black;"><b>Language Proficiency</b></label><br />
<p>Proficiency level 0-poor; 10-excellent</p>


<table border="2" bordercolor="gray" align="center">

<tr> 
 <td>
  <label for="malay" type="text" id="malay" placeholder="Malay" style="color:black; width:200px"><b>Malay</b></label><br />
 </td> 

 <td>
  <input name="malay" type="text" class="form-control" maxlength="100" style="width: 200px" />

 </td> 
</tr>  

<tr> 
 <td>
  <label for="english" type="text" id="english" placeholder="English" style="color:black; width:200px"><b>English</b></label><br />
 </td> 

 <td>
  <input name="english" type="text" class="form-control" maxlength="100" style="width: 200px" />

 </td> 
</tr>  

<tr> 
 <td>
  <label for="mandarin" type="text" id="mandarin" placeholder="Mandarin" style="color:black; width:200px"><b>Mandarin</b></label><br />
 </td> 

 <td>
  <input name="mandarin" type="text" class="form-control" maxlength="100" style="width: 200px" />

 </td> 
</tr>

<tr> 
 <td>
  <label for="other" type="text" id="other" placeholder="Other" style="color:black; width:200px"><b>Others</b></label><br />
 </td> 

 <td>
  <input name="other" type="text" class="form-control" maxlength="100" style="width: 200px" />

 </td> 
</tr>  

</table>


<!--about me -->

<tr> <td colspan="2">
<label for="aboutme" type="text" id="aboutme"  style="color:black;"><b>About Me</b></label><br />
<p>Summarize your employement history (Not more than 100 words)</p>
<textarea class="form-control" rows="6" id="aboutme" name="aboutme" maxlength="400" style="width: 560px" placeholder="Example: Early 30s. Master's Degree in Business Administration and Degree in Accounting. 
Total 19 years of working experience in Sales & Business Development in various industries. Good Exposure in Regional Sales & Business Development and etc. Is willing to travel locally and overseas"></textarea>
</td> </tr>
</p>
 <tr>

  <td>
  <label style="color:black;">Latest passport photo</label>
   <input type="file" name="image" class="form-control" id="profile-img" required>
  <img src="" id="profile-img-tag" width="200px" />
  
  </td>
 </tr>
  
 <tr>
  
  <td>
  <label style="color:black;">File format PDF and doc only!</label>
  <input type="file" name="resume" class="form-control" required>
  </td>
  
 </tr> 
 </table>
  
  <br/>
 

 <table>     
 
 <tr>
    
 
  <td>
  <input class="form-control" type="password" id="password" name="password" style= "width:235px"placeholder="Password *" required>
  </td>
  <br/>  
  <td>      
  <input class="form-control" type="password" id="cpassword" name="cpassword" style= "width:235px" placeholder="Confirm Password *" required>
  </td>
    </tr>
 </table>
 
<br/>
 
<br/>

<table>
 <td class="form-group checkbox">
                <label  style="color:black;"><input type="checkbox"> I hereby declare all informations are true and in current situation. Any discrepancies will result in penalty or termination</label>
              </td>
     
</table>


<table>  
    <td class="form-group">
                <button class="btn btn-flat btn-success">Register</button>
      </td>
 </table>
</form>
```

so, this is basically what I have and I don't know what else should I do so that the image stored is in png and I can call the image properly. Thank you in advance for all the kind helps

Comment: I don't spot a bug in the code. Maybe you fixed it in between?

Comment: yeah...but because the image stored as pdf, I couldn't display the image.

Comment: You store both values in the same variable, `$filename`.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález oh, I should put the answer here, I already solved this two weeks ago. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, after going through my source code before, I now realizes my mistake was that I didn't differentiate the files for my image and resume, and since resume was placed last, the code read to save my image as pdf as well. Here is the source code that I have already repaired.

```html
<?php

//To Handle Session Variables on This Page
session_start();

//Including Database Connection From db.php file to avoid rewriting in all files
require_once("db.php");

//If user Actually clicked register button
if(isset($_POST)) {
 $user_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['user_name']);
 $ic_no = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['ic_no']);
 $nationality = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['nationality']);
 $gender = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['gender']);
 $race = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['race']);
 $ic_no = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['ic_no']);
 $contactno = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['contactno']);
 $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['email']);
 $address = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['address']);
 $highest_qualification = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['highest_qualification']);
 $university = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['university']);
 $major = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['major']);
 $current_position = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['current_position']);
 $position_applied = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['position_applied']);
 $current_monthly_salary = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['current_monthly_salary']);
 $expected_monthly_salary = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['expected_monthly_salary']);
 $prefered_working_location = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['prefered_working_location']);
 $avaibility = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['avaibility']);
 $malay = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['malay']);
 $english = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['english']); 
 $mandarin = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['mandarin']);
 $other = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['other']);
 $aboutme = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['aboutme']);

    
 $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['password']);
 $password = base64_encode(strrev(md5($password)));

    //sql query to check if email already exists or not
    $sql = "SELECT email FROM users WHERE email='$email'";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    //if email not found then we can insert new data
    if($result->num_rows == 0) {

            //This variable is used to catch errors doing upload process. False means there is some error and we need to notify that user.
    $uploadOk = true;



 // Code for image
 if(is_uploaded_file ( $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'] )) {

  $folder_dir = "../uploads/logo/";

  $base = basename($_FILES['image']['name']); 

  $imageFileType = pathinfo($base, PATHINFO_EXTENSION); 

  $file = uniqid() . "." . $imageFileType; 
   
  $filename = $folder_dir .$file;  

  if(file_exists($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'])) { 

   if($imageFileType == "jpg" || $imageFileType == "png")  {

    if($_FILES['image']['size'] < 500000) { // File size is less than 5MB

     //If all above condition are met then copy file from server temp location to uploads folder.
     move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"], $filename);

    } else {
     $_SESSION['uploadError'] = "Wrong Size. Max Size Allowed : 5MB";
     header("Location: edit-company.php");
     exit();
    }
   } else {
    $_SESSION['uploadError'] = "Wrong Format. Only jpg & png Allowed";
    header("Location: edit-company.php");
    exit();
   }
  }
 } else {
  $uploadOk = false;
 }
  // Code for resume

 
    $folder_dir = "uploads/resume/";
    $base = basename($_FILES['resume']['name']); 
    $resumeFileType = pathinfo($base, PATHINFO_EXTENSION); 
    $file1 = uniqid() . "." . $resumeFileType;   
    $filename = $folder_dir .$file1;  
    if(file_exists($_FILES['resume']['tmp_name'])) { 

        if($resumeFileType == "pdf"|| $resumeFileType == "doc")  {
            if($_FILES['resume']['size'] < 500000) { 
   
                move_uploaded_file($_FILES["resume"]["tmp_name"], $filename);

            } else {
              
                $_SESSION['uploadError'] = "Wrong Size. Max Size Allowed : 5MB";
                $uploadOk = false;
            }
        } else {
        
            $_SESSION['uploadError'] = "Wrong Format. Only PDF Allowed";
            $uploadOk = false;
        }
    } else {
            //File not copied to temp location error.
            $_SESSION['uploadError'] = "Something Went Wrong. File Not Uploaded. Try Again.";
            $uploadOk = false;
        }

    //If there is any error then redirect back.
    if($uploadOk == false) {
        header("Location: register-candidates.php");
        exit();
    }

        $hash = md5(uniqid());


        //sql new registration insert query
  $sql="INSERT INTO users (user_name, ic_no, gender, email, password, address, nationality, contactno, highest_qualification, university, major, current_position,
  position_applied, current_monthly_salary, expected_monthly_salary, prefered_working_location, avaibility, malay, english, mandarin, other, logo, resume, hash, aboutme) VALUES
  ('$user_name', '$ic_no', '$gender', '$email', '$password', '$address', '$nationality', '$contactno', '$highest_qualification', '$university', '$major', '$current_position',
  '$position_applied', '$current_monthly_salary', '$expected_monthly_salary', '$prefered_working_location', '$avaibility', '$malay', '$english', '$mandarin',
  '$other', '$file', '$file1', '$hash', '$aboutme')";
  
  
  
        if($conn->query($sql)===TRUE) {
            // Send Email

            // $to = $email;

            // $subject = "Job Portal - Confirm Your Email Address";

            // $message = '

            // <html>
            // <head>
            //  <title>Confirm Your Email</title>
            // <body>
            //  <p>Click Link To Confirm</p>
            //  <a href="yourdomain.com/verify.php?token='.$hash.'&email='.$email.'">Verify Email</a>
            // </body>
            // </html>
            // ';

            // $headers[] = 'MIME-VERSION: 1.0';
            // $headers[] = 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1';
            // $headers[] = 'To: '.$to;
            // $headers[] = 'From: hello@yourdomain.com';
            // //you add more headers like Cc, Bcc;

            // $result = mail($to, $subject, $message, implode("\r\n", $headers)); // \r\n will return new line. 

            // if($result === TRUE) {

            //  //If data inserted successfully then Set some session variables for easy reference and redirect to login
            //  $_SESSION['registerCompleted'] = true;
            //  header("Location: login.php");
            //  exit();

            // }

            // //If data inserted successfully then Set some session variables for easy reference and redirect to login
            $_SESSION['registerCompleted'] = true;
            header("Location: login-candidates.php");
            exit();
        } else {
            //If data failed to insert then show that error. Note: This condition should not come unless we as a developer make mistake or someone tries to hack their way in and mess up :D
            echo "Error " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
        }
    } else {
        //if email found in database then show email already exists error.
        $_SESSION['registerError'] = true;
        header("Location: candidate-register.php");
        exit();
    }

    //Close database connection. Not compulsory but good practice.
    $conn->close();

} else {
    //redirect them back to register page if they didn't click register button
    header("Location: candidate-register.php");
    exit();
}
?>
```

Hope this will be useful for other programmers in the future!